# Sum from $n=1$ to $N$ of $\sin(nx)/2^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

The question states:

[image]

I'm not sure what to do here. I used the geometric sum to do $2^{-n}$, but I can't think of a way to sum $\sin(n\theta)$ to get the required RHS.

---

Further working

[image]

Apologies for maybe being slow or missing something obvious here... I don't know how to get it into required form.

Comment: Just a random edit to note:  \$\sin(x)\$ inexplicably looks much better than  \$sin(x)\$

Answer (score 3):

The solution below is just to give a basic proof without using Euler's identity. 
\begin{align*}
&\quad \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{2^n} \cdot 2^N(5-4\cos\theta) \\
&=  \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2^{n-1}\sin(N-n+1)\theta \right)(1+4-4\cos \theta) \\
&= \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2^{n-1}\sin(N-n+1)\theta \right) + \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2^{n+1}\sin(N-n+1)\theta \right) \\
&\quad -  \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2^{n+1}\sin(N-n+1)\theta\cos\theta \right) \\
&=  \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2^{n-1}\sin(N-n+1)\theta \right) +  \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2^{n+1}\sin(N-n+1)\theta \right) \\
&\quad - \left( \sum_{n=1}^N 2^n [\sin(N-n+2)\theta + \sin(N-n)\theta] \right) \\
&= \left[ 2^{N-1}\sin\theta + \sum_{n=2}^{N-1}2^{n-1}\sin(N-n+1)\theta + \sin(N\theta) \right] \\
&\quad + \left[ 2^{N+1}\sin\theta + \sum_{n=2}^{N-1}2^{n+1}\sin(N-n+1)\theta + 2^2\sin(N\theta) \right] \\
&\quad - \left[ 2\sin(N+1)\theta + 2^2\sin(N\theta) + \sum_{n=2}^{N-1}2^{n+1}\sin(N-n+1)\theta + \sum_{n=2}^{N-1}2^{n-1}\sin(N-n+1)\theta + 2^{N-1}\sin\theta \right] \\
&= 2^{N+1}\sin\theta + \sin(N\theta) - 2\sin((N+1)\theta).
\end{align*}
But I do spend almost half an hour to write it, hah.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Euler's identity says: $$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$

$\implies\dfrac{\sin n\theta}{2^n}=$ imaginary part of $\left(\dfrac{e^{i\theta}}2\right)^n$

Answer (score 2):

$$e^{inx}=\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx),$$
yet $$e^{-inx}=\cos(nx)-i\sin(nx)$$

so we can deduce that $$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i}.$$

This is annoying, but will get the job done. See [Dirichlet Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel), which uses a similar method, and is somewhat related (at least you know this is not a meaningless computation.)

The hint was intended to suggest that you wanted something of the form $a\cdot r^n,$ and in this case, you are summing over the sum of two power series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2^{n+1}i}.$$

---

**Edit:**

\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2^{n+1}i}&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{e^{inx}}{2^{n+1}i}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{e^{-inx}}{2^{n+1}i}\\
&=\frac{1}{2i}\left(  \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{e^{inx}}{2^n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{e^{-inx}}{2^{n}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2i}\left(  \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{2}\right)^n-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^n\right)
\end{align*}
'
Use the hint, along with my comment. Notice what "$r$" is, and see if you can finish the problem.

Comment: i'm quite confused as how to use the sum. The sum a$r^n$ is given from n = 0 to N-1, but the sum i need is from 1 to N. In addition, from the power series, I'm not sure what I'd be using as r?

Comment: Try writing the general equation (the formula written) and multiplying both sides by  $r$ ;)

Comment: multiplied by r - i think i understand that each time you multiply by $e^{ix}$, you go from $\sin(nx) to \sin(n+1)x)$however nothing happens to the $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: This is true, but not what I had in mind. Take: $$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} r^n=\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}$$ and then multiply both sides by $r$ to get $$\frac{r-r^{n+1}}{1-r}=r \cdot\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} r^n=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} r^{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{N} r^{n}$$

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: I see! Sorry - we haven't actually studied series yet, I did a bit back in high school but am not familiar with these tricks, or using them with complex numbers. I will work through the series to try and get the answer required now. However, why do you use $e^{ix}$ your r, and not $e^{ix}/2$

Comment: Awesome! Good luck

Comment: That was sloppiness, the latter is correct.

Comment: I've tried to work through it but its not falling out. by applying the formula for r from your comment i got an equation, however I don't know how to reduce that to the answer. I tried using the half angle trick, to multiply top and bottom by $e^{+- (ix/2)}$ but it won't fall out. See my edit.